# Is this a correct method using free() in C?

Tags: c

If I have this function `foo()` and I'm calling it from another function `foo2()`; must I free the memory in the calling function like this?

```
char *foo(char *str1){
    char *str2;
    str2 = malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(str1)) + 1);
    memcpy(str2, str1, strlen(str1) + 1)
    return str2;
}

void foo2(void){
    char *str1 = "Hello world!"
    char *str2;
    str2 = foo(str1);
    ...some stuff
    free(str2); //Should I do this here?
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are not the same thing. I removed the C++ tag, since you mention C, and the code posted is clearly not C++.

Comment: Why can't you use `memcpy()` directly in `foo2`? And wouldn't it depend on what you're using `str1` and `str2` for?

Comment: The multiplication by `sizeof(char)` is a little odd.  Logically, it should be `sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1) + 1)`, since the extra 1 is also a `char`. OTOH, since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, it is not necessary.  Were you messing with arrays of structures, and you needed the `+1`, it would be crucial to multiply it all by the size of the structure.

Comment: @user49164: The code can't use `memcpy()` directly in `foo2()` because there is no space allocated for `str2` to point at. You must ensure that pointers point at allocated space before trying to copy over that space. Presumably, the code `...some stuff` could be modifying its copy of `"Hello world!", which would not be safe on `str1` since the string literal is probably in read-only memory. It might be different given `char str1[] = "Hello world!";` as that is a modifiable string. Perhaps the original is needed again, untouched.  It does depend...but since the code copies, that is necessary.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes...You are correct that C and C++ are not the same thing.  But C is a subset of C++, therfore C code is C++ code.

Comment: @ToddMurray Wrong. C and C++ *have a common subset*. But that subset *is not C*. This code here even happens to be proof of that. Try compiling it in a C++ compiler and you'll see why. `char* str = malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(str1)) + 1);` is not valid C++. http://ideone.com/Pcx5P

Comment: If you don't call `free()` in `foo2()`, you leak memory, and memory leaks are bad.  You could also make it `char *foo(char const *str1)` which documents better that it does not modify the original string.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes Compiles with gcc as c++....that is with the requisite cleanup (missing ;s, etc)...the only thing that was needed for the malloc line was to add a cast to char*....

Comment: @ToddMurray *But that's no longer the same code*. The code without the cast is valid C. You can't say that "C code is C++ code" when you mean "C code if you change some things is C++ code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is right. `foo()` allocates some memory and it must be freed by the caller. It's not a very good design but it works. It could be better if `foo()` accepts two parameters: output buffer and its size.

```
void foo(char* input, char* output, int* bufferSize);
```

If output is `NULL` the required size is written in `bufferSize` by `foo()`.

Comment: The original is a perfectly valid design.  Your alternative is just about valid, though more unwieldy.  Frankly, the pointer to size would annoy the living daylights out of me.  I'd want to use `foo(var_to_copy, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` and not being able to do so would be irksome in the extreme.  It would be far better (IMNSHO) for `foo()` to insist on `assert(output != 0 && bufferSize > 0);`.  And having the function return the pointer it is passed can be useful, too: `char *foo(char const *input, char *output, size_t outlen);`.

Comment: I guess we're talking about opinions (more or less) but...
I understand the pointer to size is annoying whenever you know the maximum size allowed (but in C you may provide a helper macro to hide it). That function style doesn't come to make code more elegant (and short) but more safe. I really agree with the return type but I would prefer an error code ('cause it may fail) instead of a pointer to the argument. ANYWAY...after all I guess the answer is _coherence_ with the rest of the application.

Comment: It seems the OP agrees with you.  Yes, it is subjective, depending on the application and personal or project coding style.  Being able to interrogate for the required length can be helpful in other contexts than this one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Also, `int *` is a horribly wrong type for a buffer size. At the very least it should be `size_t *`...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, except you don't test that your malloc is successful

Answer (score 2):

You can free the allocated memory anywhere given the fact that you did the allocation, that the allocation was successful, and that the memory was not already freed.

Comment: I'd add to that for the OP's benefit that my general rule of thumb though is to attempt to free the memory in the same "unit" where I allocated it. My definition of unit is fairly loose here, and corresponds more to my internal conception of how the program is put together than any particular syntactic construction.

Comment: @deong: This basically makes any sort of object oriented programming in C impossible, since the standard idiom for that is to have a function that "creates an object" of some type via `malloc` and filling in initial values, then returns a pointer, which the caller would later pass to a function for "destroying" that type of object.

Comment: @R: That's sort of what I meant by having a very loose definition of "unit". I'm not sure of a better way to describe the point, maybe "symmetry" captures some of what I'm going for. Allocate at the beginning of a block, deallocate at the end is symmetrical. Allocate in a create method, deallocate in a free method is symmetrical. Allocate in a create function, deallocate in the middle of some logic somewhere else isn't and feels wrong. That's also what I was getting at by saying it's more of a conceptual level than a syntactic one.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah that would work, however you have a bug:

```
char *foo(const char *str1)
{
    char *str2 = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(str1)) + 1);
    if (str2 != NULL)
        memcpy(str2, str1, strlen(str1) + 1);
    return str2;
}
void foo2
{
    char *str1 = "Hello world!"
    char *str2;
    str2 = foo(str1);
    ...some stuff
    free(str2);
}
```

Conventionally you would document the fact that the caller is responsible for freeing the returned pointer using `free()`.

Also your `foo()` function is nothing more than `strdup()`.

Comment: thanks it's not tested is only a example to explain this better

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The memory needs to be freed at some point. As you can see, you now have a tight coupling between the `foo` function and any of its callers. One common alternative is to pass in a pointer to a `char` array and the size of it. The function then returns whether it filled out the array properly. This moves the responsibility of both allocating and freeing to the caller.

```
bool * foo(char * str, size_t size)
{
  if(size < FOO_REQUIRED_SIZE) {
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    ...
    return TRUE;
  }
}

void foo2(void)
{
  char str[FOO_REQUIRED_SIZE];
  foo(str, ARRAY_SIZE(str));
}
```

Instead of simply returning `FALSE` if the function failed, you can furthermore document the required size of the array. Or alternatively provide a function which calculates the required size and returns it.

```
size_t getRequiredBufSizeForFoo()
{
  // Calculate how many bytes required
  return ...;
}

void foo2(void)
{
  size_t len = getRequiredBufSizeForFoo();
  char str[len];

  foo(str, len);
}
```